# Submit with post method using jquery .ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a form that is in a dialog created with jquery UI. I am trying to send the form to a php controller with a `jquery.ajax()` request, but **i want the request to be handled like if it was submited from an php page and execute the controller (not only get the response with AJAX).**

The reason why is because i want to add aditional data in the request that is not in the form itself, and seems easier for me to add it with jquery.

This is the form:

```
<form action="">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="name">Soci:</label>
            <p id="soci_data"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="month">Mes:</label>
            <p id="mes_data"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="dropdown_payed"class="form-group">
                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-small">
                <option>payed</option>
                <option>not payed</option>
                </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The only form field i want to submit is the dropdown menu.

And this is the `.ajax()` request:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"update.php",
    data:{
        id_month:idmonth,
        id_name:idname,
        payed: $("#dropdown_payed").val();
        }
    success:function(data){
        // To do when the request succeded
    }
});
```

The controller `update.php` right now only prints the information passed in the request to see if get the data that i am expecting with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: > i want the request to be handled like if it was submited from an php page and execute the controller not only get the response with AJAX.  Didn't get it. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @FernandoCarvalhosa i don't know exactly how to explain it. I mean like if it was submited with a button with this propertys without any javascript: `<form action="update.php" method="post"><button type="submit" </button>`

Comment: You can get the same data from the server through ajax or normal requests, the difference will be on the client treatment of the response. If you submit a `<form action="update.php">`, the client will redirect you to that page and render the response from update.php controller. That's what you want to happen?

Comment: Maybe jQuery Form Plugin will help you http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: @FernandoCarvalhosa yes that is it, but i want to add extra data that is not actually in the form, i have available this extra information inside the javascript function that i use to display the dialog. But i don't know how to do this. Also i don't know if ajax is the way to go but seemed an option. Is there a way to do it only with jqery?

Comment: You could use `<input type="hidden">` in the form and submit extra data that doesn't show up to users. Does that works for you?

Comment: @FernandoCarvalhosa yes that does the trick, i add the values with jquery to the hidden input once loaded, and then use the button to submit a standard request. i didn't thought in that. Thank you very much!.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Posted as an answer for you to accept and help other people with the same problem as yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<input type="hidden">` in the form and submit the extra data that doesn't show up to users. Does that works for you?